# Understanding the Entity Framework when updating record from specific select query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Hope some one can help me understand more on how the .net core entity framework works in the scenario below.

I have an update function and it works perfectly fine.
But when I tried optimizing my select query, that is when I'm hitting an error.
To give a better understanding, here are 3 classes and its relationship that is involved:

```
public class Dealer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    ...
    public int DealerId { get; set; }
    public Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accessory> Accessories { get; set; }
}

public class Accessory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string VehicleId { get; set; }
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the function where I update the data.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var dealer = _dealerService.Get(123);
    ... // some dealer field value changes

    var vehicle = new Vehicle { ... };
    vehicle.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    vehicle.Accessories.Add(new Accessory { ... });
    dealer.Vehicles.Add(new List<Vehicle> { vehicle });

    _dealerService.Update(dealer);
}
```

The working version is just a simple select method that takes every field for the Dealer by default:

```
public Dealer Get(int id)
{
    return _db.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Based on the logs it can be seen that the magic happens in the following sequence:

1. INSERT INTO [Vehicles]
2. UPDATE [Dealers]
3. INSERT INTO [Accessories]

Now I'm trying to optimize the speed and because Dealer has plenty of fields, I decided to select only fields that are needed for the Dealer so that the query takes a shorter time. Hence, I updated the method like so

```
public Dealer Get(int id)
{
    return _db.Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .Select(x => new Dealer 
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            ...
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

That's when I'm hit with this error 
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Accessories_Vehicles_Id". The conflict occurred in database, table "dbo.Vehicles", column 'Id'.

```
INSERT INTO [Accessories] ([Name], [Quantity], [VehicleId])  
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);  
SELECT [Id] FROM [Accessories] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
```

And it is obvious why from the logs as it tries to INSERT INTO [Accessories] first instead of the working version that is the third step.

So here I am hoping someone can explain why by specifying specific fields for my select query can result in such a behavior where .net inserts Accessories first instead of Vehicles first when there is a FK involved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the table `Vehicles` have auto PK on?

Comment: @JohnB Sorry, I've updated the code. Vehicles is actually using guid as its Id.